# No connection to gradle server. Try restarting the server

Tags: visual-studio, selenium, gradle

Me tira error en Selenium con la conección al gradle, lo tengo instalado en la misma carpeta donde esta todo del proyecto, es la última version, gracias[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Benvenido, ¿cual es el error?, no se ve la imagen, agrega como texto el código, revisar [Ask], saludos.

Comment: Ya agregué otra foto, gracias!